# 16.04 Live vs GParted

Tags: gparted

I have made a Live 16.04 pendrive using SDC, (no persistence option available), and also tried UNetbootin-windows 613, (persistent). The drive is 4GB.

When I look at the drive in GParted on a 14.04 computer I am given a Libparted warning about GPT signatures, no valid fake MSDOS...GParted then shows the drive as only having unallocated space.

When I look at the drive in GParted when booted from the Live 16.04 drive the Libparted warning tells me the driver descriptor says block size is 2048b but Linux says 512b.

If I click ignore, GParted then shows unknown first partition of 4KiB, unllocated second partition of 1.38GiB, 2.31 MiB fat16 third partition and 13.99 GiB unallocated forth partition. (which is a lot of free space for a 4GB drive).

I have also not been unable to edit grub.cfg, txt.cfg or syslinux.cfg (to use persistence).

I am wondering what is up? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Perhaps you have a hybrid GPT/MSDOS partition table on the drive?  These are often seen with OS X, but are not normal for GNU/Linux or Windows.  If you need both then be sure to keep these in sync with a tool like gptsync.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both GPT and MSDOS tables, I am wondering if this is a bug with Startup Disk Creator in 16.04, and If it is happening to others.

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing the broken GPT with the following steps.

1. From a terminal window run:

   ```
   sudo gdisk /path-to-usb-drive
   ```

   Where */path-to-usb-drive* is something like /dev/sdc.
2. Use **x** to enter the expert menu.
3. Use **z** to zap the GPT.
4. Use **w** to write the partition table and exit.

The msdos partition table (aka MBR) will be the only partition table remaining.